# Svelte each block different referenced result at event handling function

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I've try below different way to change object props in each block, but having the different result.

First I using inline anonymous function is dose change the cat name in the each block, like **step 1** in the below code.

But when I call the event handler in named function it dose not change in each block at all, like **step 2**.

Finally I try assign props in inline function first then call the named function it change the value too, like **step 3**.

I am curious why **step 2** way is not working to change the value in each block.

Thanks for reading !

```
<script>
    let cats = [
        { id: 'J---aiyznGQ', name: 'Keyboard Cat' },
        { id: 'z_AbfPXTKms', name: 'Maru' },
        { id: 'OUtn3pvWmpg', name: 'Henri The Existential Cat' }
    ];
    const named = (cat) => cat.name = 'named';
</script>

<h1>The Famous Cats of YouTube</h1>

<ul>
    {#each cats as cat (cat.id)}
        // step 1. referenced
        <li on:click={()=>cat.name='inline'}>{cat.name}</li>
        // step 2. not referenced
        <li on:click={()=>named(cat)}>{cat.name}</li>
        // step 3. referenced
        <li on:click={()=>{
            cat.name='inline';
            named(cat);
            }}>{cat.name}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Svelte's reactivity is triggered by assignments, so updating `cat.name` won't automatically update references to `cats`, unless you follow it up with `cats = cats`, like this:

```html
<ul>
    {#each cats as cat (cat.id)}
        <li on:click={() => { cat.name = 'inline'; cats = cats; } }>{cat.name}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Therefore, another solution is to update the `cats` object itself:

```html
<ul>
    {#each cats as cat, i (cat.id)}
        <li on:click={() => cats[i].name = 'inline'}>{cat.name}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi lucas thanks for your reply , in my question step1 is update and cats = cats is no needed , I know svelte is triggered by assignment so that is the question how step 1&3 is work but step 2 is not.

Comment: @user3474979 It's the same principle, your `named` function should update the object `cats`, like this: `const named = (cat) => { cat.name = 'named'; cats = cats; };`

Comment: Hi Lucas thanks for replay, I mean <li on:click={()=>cat.name='inline'}> this one actually work as a charm without assign. Both of step 1&3 is not triggered assignment but is still work.

Comment: I get it now. After asking some kind people about it on Svelte's Discord, I discovered that the function `named` is changing the value of `cat.name`, which is inside the `each` block scope, and that's why doing it inline works and inside a function doesn't.

Comment: Yes, But in the step 3 after inline change cat name then call the function named is still work too to change the cat.name value to named.